# Django Generic Foreign Key: how do I retrieve all content objects for a set of objects with the generic foreign key?

Tags: django, django-queryset, generic-foreign-key

Hello I have a model that uses a generic foreign key to be attached to several different other models. I want to get all of those content objects in a single query.

I created a data structure with all of the content type ids and and the object ids. How do I get a bulk set of content objects using the content type ids and object ids? Instead of having to do a query for each of these content objects, can I do a single query to get them all?

Comment: What does your data structure look like? I would imagine it's like {contenttype1: [id1, id2], contenttype2: [id3, id4]}? Since generic foreign key is composed of 2 things together, I don't think it's possible to get results in one query, but above data structure would reduce your number of queries to number of contenttypes you have got.

Comment: Yes, that is the structure I am using. Given all the content types and object ids, will I just have to manually get the objects using the class name and the ids for the given content type? Like `MyConnectedObject_<x>.objects.filter(id__in=<object_id_list>)` for each of the connected object types. I should be able to do that. There are about 10 different objects that connect to this, so I'll need 10 queries, but that's better than one query for each of the several thousand items I have that have a foreign key back to the 10 different `MyConnectedObject<x>` classes. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: I can't go any further from that, but there's should be far less content types than ids, so just hit the database for each contenttype you have(with `id__in` statement to get all objects) wouldn't be too bad, unless you need only ONE queryset, which I couldn't help.

Comment: That makes sense. It would be nice if Django could retrieve a set of objects connected to several other objects all in one, but 10 queries is better than 1000s! :-)  I see how this could not be a QuerySet, since they would all be from different tables with different fields, but it would be nice to get a list of Objects based on the foreign key field. Thanks again!